# UM7 accel drift

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experiencing some odd behavior with my CH Robotics UM7 IMU that I recently purhcased. When the unit is just sitting on the table, it reads 9.2 instead of 9.8 m/s/s for acceleration. I can find instructions on how to zero the rate gyros but nowhere does it mention calibrating the accelerometers. Has anyone run into something similar before with these IMUs or any other unit? I have included an example message

```
header: 
  seq: 3506
  stamp: 
    secs: 1450136355
    nsecs: 252817294
  frame_id: imu_link
orientation: 
  x: -0.0238677723
  y: 0.0203094265
  z: -0.9840840295
  w: -0.1747282065
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.000581685356641
  y: -0.000610669209776
  z: 7.07960511619e-05
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.0682945557769
  y: 0.22608049971
  z: 9.21032193719
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222535/um7-accel-drift/) by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [J-rizzy](https://answers.ros.org/users/27021/j-rizzy/) on 2016-09-01**:
Hey, did you ever end up figuring out how to fix this problem?  I'm getting a similar error with my new UM7, where my z-acceleration is hovering at around 10 m/s^2 when resting.  My UM7 is running firmware version U72A.

**Comment by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on 2016-09-01**:
Yes I did. The UM7 (and all accelerometers) are very sensitive to mechanical strain, temperature and a variety of other factors. As such, you need to calibrate the accelerometer fairly frequently. I would suggest the CH Robotics utility to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, UM7 has a Windows software for calibration and configuration. You can try it for calibration, after that return back to Linux.

Software is [here](http://www.chrobotics.com/serial-interface).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0